# Is there a quick way to gather (or buy) raw meat in Monster Hunter Tri?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-tri

I've played a lot of Monster Hunter on the PSP and recently started playing it on the Wii. I've not played online yet as I've been working my way through the single player missions. Just to give an idea as to where I'm at, I've just started the 5 star quests.

My question is if there is a quick way to gather (or buy) raw meat, aside from going out into the woods and killing everything I see. To my knowledge you can buy raw meat in some of the PSP versions of MH, which has me wondering if I can do the same here.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that there's any way to buy it, but you can gather it pretty quickly if you run into zone two and kill the Apotoths there. After you kill or route a herd there, another will come into the zone soon. New herds will stop coming after a few times, and then you can head back to village, come back to zone two, and kill them all again.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need raw meat for stamina, you should go for energy drinks: its ingredients are farmable, it works under water and it also negates sleepness.

So farming raw meat can be done on Moga Woods, killing Aptonoths and Bullfangos, but you'll only use these for sleep and para meat.